# C++ makefile while seperate the declaration and implementation

Tags: c++, class, makefile

I wrote a small simple SQL interpreter in C++, in my main.cpp
the code is something like

```
#include "lexer.h"
#include "parser.h"
#include "interpreter.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //my code
}
```

In lexer.h,parser.h, interpretor.h, each contain the declaration and implementation of a class with the same name of the header file.My question is how should I write my makefile so that I can separate the declaration and implementation, for example, declaration in lexer.h, implementation in lexer.cpp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is like below

```
interpreter: main.cc lexer.cc parser.cc interpreter.cc
         g++ -o interpreter main.cc lexer.cc parser.cc interpreter.cc -I
```

but sometimes is useful to use different targets. **This is because if you modify a single file in your project, you don't have to recompile everything, only what you modified**.So you can do like below

**Using dependencies**

```
all: interpreter

interpreter: main.o lexer.o parser.o interpreter.o
    g++ main.o lexer.o parser.o interpreter.o -o interpreter

main.o: main.cc
    g++ -c main.cc

lexer.o: lexer.cc
    g++ -c lexer.cc

parser.o: parser.cc
    g++ -c parser.cc

interpreter.o: interpreter.cc
    g++ -c interpreter.cc

clean:
    rm -rf *o hello
```

**Using variables and comments**
We can also use variables when writing Makefiles

```
# Implementing a new sql lexer the variable CC will be
# the compiler to use.
CC=g++
# these flags will be passed to the compiler.
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
    all: interpreter

    interpreter: main.o lexer.o parser.o interpreter.o
        $(CC) main.o lexer.o parser.o interpreter.o -o interpreter

    main.o: main.cc
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cc

    lexer.o: lexer.cc
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) lexer.cc

    parser.o: parser.cc
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) parser.cc

    interpreter.o: interpreter.cc
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) interpreter.cc

    clean:
        rm -rf *o hello
```

Comment: You can remove most of the rules and let make work with the implicit ones.

Comment: Is it intentional that most of the second code block is indented?